# How to pass sql array to promises

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have this code working but very much dependent of query parameters. Each query based on request parameter.

```
var query1P = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM C");

var query3P = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM A");

Promise.all([query1P query3P]).spread(function (result, result3) {
res.status(200).json({ table: result.rows, table3: result3.rows });
return connection.close();
})
.catch(function (err) {
console.log(err.message);
return connection.close();
});
```

How can I pass query array in Promise.all something like

> queryArray = [query1P, query2P, query3P]

and get the results back in array. Is there anything in promises where I can loop through queryArray ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't pass an array literal, and don't use `spread`  instead of `then`?

Answer (score 0):

This should happen automatically (although I notice there is no comma between query1P and query3P in your `Promise.all()` call. Also, `.spread()` should be replace with `.then()`

```js
Promise.all(['test', 'blah'])
    .then(function(responses) {
        console.log(responses);
    })
```

Just replace 'test' and 'blah' with actual promises that will resolve eventually.

Comment: Can I do like this `Promise.all([array])
    .then(function(responses) {
        console.log(responses);
    })`

Comment: Exactly. The first argument passed to the .then() function is an array of the responses of the requests that were passed into the .all() method.